# How to checkout a CVS branch HEAD using IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, branch, cvs, vcs-checkout

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.
How to check out the HEAD of a CVS branch?

I can only check out the HEAD of the main stream, or a tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CVS integration in IDEA is a bit strange in that regard. You need to create a new *CVS Configuration* (i.e. CVS Root) for the branch. So rather than having a single connection configuration that you use to connect and then select a branch, you need a separate connection configuration for each branch. In the *CVS Root* dialog, you define the branch.

[image]

**[EDIT]**

Remember that in CVS, a branch is just a sticky tag and thus why you enter the branch name in the "By tag" field.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it does not work for me. In deed, I was able to create an IDEA module from a "branch" of CVS by using a new configuration CVS just like what you had said, but, I am not able to make any commit for modified files. The error message reads: `sticky tag <version name like 1.19.6.5> for file <file name> is not a branch`.

Comment: I have found a solution to that error in IntelliJ 12.1 Web Help [page](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/resolving-commit-errors.html). I updated the file with resetting sticky data and then I was allowed to commit my changes.